# Looping over two arrays with different length, and correctly sorting the output

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say that you have two arrays - *headline* and *content*.
*headline* will contain either 1, 2 or 3 strings.
*content* will contain either 3, 6 or 9 strings.

I need to loop over these arrays. 
The output I'm trying to get:

```
Headline1
Content1
Content2
Content3
Headline2
Content4
Content5
Content6
Headline3
Content7
Content8
Content9
```

This nested loop doesn't work, since it puts every content underneath each headline.

```
headline = ["Headline1", "Headline2", "Headline3"];
content = ["Content1", "Content2", "Content3", 
           "Content4", "Content5", "Content6",
           "Content7", "Content8", "Content9"];

for(var i = 0; i < headline.length; i++){
    console.log(headline[i]);
  for(var j = 0; j < content.length; j++){
    console.log(content[j]);
  }
}
```

I'm getting the strings from a form, and pushing them into an array.
The length of the array depends on how many fields the user wishes to use.
Any suggestions on how I could tackle this problem?

Comment: any reason not to use objects?

Comment: How do you know which contents go under each headline? Is it always 3 contents for each?

Comment: @Barmar There is always 3 contents for each. 1-3 will go under the first headline, 4-6 under the second, and 7-9 under the third.

Comment: @StephanBakkelundValois You don't need to change your array as one answer is suggesting that. Please have a look at other solutions as they are more focused on what you asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner loop should only loop 3 times, not for all of `content.length`. To get the appropriate entry in content, use `i*3+j`.

```js
headline = ["Headline1", "Headline2", "Headline3"];
content = ["Content1", "Content2", "Content3",
  "Content4", "Content5", "Content6",
  "Content7", "Content8", "Content9"
];

for (var i = 0; i < headline.length; i++) {
  console.log(headline[i]);
  for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    console.log(content[i * 3 + j]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a valuable bit of information. You need to know how many "contents" you put under each "header". From the data you provided, there is no way to tell that, if it can be 1, 2, or 3.

What you have to do when you get the content coming in is do an array of array (or some other structure) to group the right fields.

```
var headline = ["Headline1", "Headline2", "Headline3"];
var content = [["Content1", "Content2", "Content3"], 
           ["Content4", "Content5", "Content6"],
           ["Content7", "Content8", "Content9"]];
```

Notice the extra pairs of `[]` grouping contents together.

After that, it's fairly trival.

```
for(var i = 0; i < headline.length; i++){
    console.log(headline[i]);
  for(var j = 0; j < content[i].length; j++){
    console.log(content[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Noticed we're now using `content[i].length` instead of just `content.length` and `content[i][j]` for the `console.log` instead of just `content[j]`.

For each headline-n, we're getting the nth set of contents and looping through those.

---

As an aside, for performance-sake, it's best to save your length to a variable in the loop:

```
for(var i = 0, iLen = headline.length; i < iLen; i++) { 
    console.log(headline[i]);
    for (var j = 0, jLen = content[i].length; j < jLen; j++) {
        console.log(content[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Doing that will save it from doing a whole lot of checks of the length, which can make a difference for a large set of results.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single loop and get the header depending of the content and header length.

```js
var headline = ["Headline1", "Headline2", "Headline3"],
    content = ["Content1", "Content2", "Content3", "Content4", "Content5", "Content6", "Content7", "Content8", "Content9"],
    l = Math.floor(content.length / headline.length);
  
content.forEach(function (a, i) {
    if (!(i % l) ) {
        console.log(headline[Math.floor(i / l)]);
    }
    console.log(a);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend rearranging the data into array of objects such as:

```
headlines = [
{ 
  title:  'Headline1',
  contents: [
    "Content1", 
    "Content2", 
    "Content3"
  ]
},{ 
  title:  'Headline2',
  contents: [
    "Content4", 
    "Content5", 
    "Content6"
  ]
},
{ ... }
];
```

If you can't do that for some reasons, the following loop should work:

```
headline = ["Headline1", "Headline2", "Headline3"];
content = ["Content1", "Content2", "Content3", 
           "Content4", "Content5", "Content6",
           "Content7", "Content8", "Content9"];

for(var i=0, l=headline.length; i<l; i++){
  console.log(headline[i]);
  for(var j=i*3; j<3*i+3; j++){
    console.log(content[j]);
  }
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here an easy programmatic solution for you:

```
var j=0,k=1;
var iter=content.length/headline.length;

for(var i=0;i<iter;i++){
    console.log(headline[i]);
    for(;j<headline.length*k;j++){
       console.log(content[j]);
   }
    k+=1;
}
```

See working on console:https://jsfiddle.net/7un047q6/

Answer (score 0):

One other way to do this could be...

```js
var headline = ["Headline1", "Headline2", "Headline3"],
     content = ["Content1", "Content2", "Content3", "Content4", "Content5", "Content6", "Content7", "Content8", "Content9"],
      result = headline.reduce((p,h,i) => [...p,h,...content.slice(i*3,i*3+3)],[]);
console.log(result);
```